# Where will ruby be installed in ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I installed ruby and rails and other gems in ubuntu via terminal using rvm

After installation i checked the version of ruby and rails.

Later i closed the terminal. now I am not able to find ruby in it.

I am new to ruby and ubuntu as well. I am sure its installed . But after closing the terminal when I open it again and type "ruby -v"

I get this :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby
 * ruby1.8 (You will have to enable component called 'universe')
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: ruby is installed in `.rvm` folder. After you install it, you need to tel rvm to use it: 'rvm use ruby`

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using `rbenv` instead of `rvm` for Ruby these days.

A guide on how to install it is located here: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10

The Ruby will then be installed in the `.rbenv` directory that is located in your `$HOME` folder.

To answer your question on where `rvm` installs it,  it is installed into `.rvm` folder in your `$HOME`